# Have different style apply to different syntax highlighter languages

Tags: jekyll, kramdown

I have a jekyll site where I post a lot of shell examples in code blocks. I struggle to visually delineate between the script/shell commands and their output of the commmands.

Generated html:

```
<pre><code class="language-powershell">
function DemoCode {
    return 'rab', 'oof'
}
DemoCode

rab
oof
</code></pre>
```

In this example, the last two lines need to be obviously the output from the first 4 lines.

Markdown is currently just normal triple-backtick with a powershell tag:

````
```powershell
function DemoCode {
    return 'rab', 'oof'
}

DemoCode

rab
oof
```
````

I'd prefer to avoid splitting it into a second code block. Wordpress let me do this with inline style tags, but it was a pig of a job.

This isn't a good solution for me but I could have a separate code block with the 'plaintext' tag to the syntax highlighter:

The best I have so far is indeed with separate code blocks. If I apply the 'plaintext' tag to rouge, then at least I don't get syntax highlighting, which helps. But the generated html still inherits the same CSS from .highlight.

Markdown:

````
```powershell
function Write-Stuff {
    Write-Output $Stuff
}
```

```plaintext
Output I would like with different color and background-color
```
````

I still need that to inherit different CSS, though. Generated HTML:

```
<div class="language-powershell highlighter-rouge"><div class="highlight"><pre class="highlight"><code><span class="c1">#this is formatted with md code block and powershell tag</span>
</code></pre></div></div>

<div class="language-plaintext highlighter-rouge"><div class="highlight"><pre class="highlight"><code>#formatted with md code block and plaintext tag
</code></pre></div></div>
```

Comment: Why not use two different code block?

Comment: That's a question about visual language. Graphic design matters, and two separate code blocks is not a solution.

A partial solution would be if the second code block was visually distinguished by, e.g., separate colour, but i can't see a way to achieve that in jekyll, since the html class is generated on commit to github pages.

Comment: What is the desired output? No styles at all?

Comment: I expect what I want isn't achievable. In order of preference:

- output is inside main fenced block, with no highlighting and with different bg / text color

- output is in fenced block within main block, no highlighting, different color

- output is in separate code block below, different color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go with separate code blocks, you can use a block IAL to set a custom class on the syntax highlighted blocks:

````
{:.my-custom-class}
``` powershell
function Write-Stuff {
    Write-Output $Stuff
    }
```
````

This would insert the `my-custom-class` right next to `language-powershell highlighter-rouge`, allowing you to customize your CSS appropriately.

As for avoiding splitting the block: That is not possible with kramdown. However, you could implement a [custom syntax highlighter](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/rdoc/Kramdown/Converter/SyntaxHighlighter.html) that knows how to do this.